# Authorization failed during category creation using REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, oauth, acl

I am playing with magento 2 Rest API to add category in magento admin. I am writing below code, but showing "401 Unauthorized" and showing message 

  Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
  
    Magento_Catalog::categories

I am using below code to add category in magento console, can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

POST Method: [MAGENTO URL]/index.php/rest/V1/categories/

Request Body:
{
  "id": 0,
  "parentId": 0,
  "name": "test category",
  "isActive": true,
  "position": 0,
  "level": 0,
  "includeInMenu": true,
  "extensionAttributes": {},
}

but not working. any solution?

Thanks

Rahul Anand.

Comment: This API has access to all resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps defined in authentication guide provided by Magento.

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html

This guide is more elaborated and helpful in achieving your requirements. Magento team has added more details in it and it will help you out in authenticating your request.

You can use any method:
- [Token based](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html)
- [Oauth based](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html)
- [Session based](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-session.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to access protected admin resource without authentication.

The easiest option for you would be to get access token using the following request:

```
curl -X POST "https://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{"username":"test@example.com", "password":"123123q"}'
```

Then specify this token (e.g. vbnf3hjklp5iuytre) in `Authotization` header while making requests to protected resources, e.g.:

```
curl -X GET "http://magento.ll/index.php/rest/V1/customers/2" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer vbnf3hjklp5iuytre"
```

Also there is no need to specify `"id": 0` in request for new category creation.

Please take a look at the [Getting started](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html) guide for Magento 2 web APIs.

Comment: hi Dude, Thanks for your help. But we are trying to run rest api code, and it keep showing that error "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources". Can you help me understanding how can we fix it?

Comment: Assuming that you generated access token for the admin user, the only problem could be that the admin does not have permissions to manage categories. Check that your user is assigned to role, which has access to this resource in System => Permissions => All Users (UserRoles)

Comment: In the example I provided you get token for Admin user, not integration. So permissions should be configured for the admin user whose `username`/`password` you specified during token request.

Comment: Hi,user is created as admin, and role is there which can access all resources. Still getting same error.

Comment: I am using Firefox rest client to make request. All credentials are given there, and also the consumer key and token too.

Comment: This is OAuth 2.0 flow, not OAuth 1.0a. So do not use REST client OAuth menu to specify consumer key. Just specify custom Authorization header with value "Bearer your-token-goes-here"

Comment: Thanks. I am trying. In the mean while dude I will be really thankful to you , if you can give me a piece of code to execute once in php please.

Comment: Take a look at API functional tests, they perform requests to REST and SOAP web APIs from PHP e.g. `\Magento\Webapi\Routing\ServiceVersionV1Test::testItem`. Here is official documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/web-api-functional-testing.html

Comment: Sorry dude I am new to this framework. If you can give me a code that will help me fixing. I am purely new bee

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to use REST client for Firefox. Or Curl, like described here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/gs-curl.html